# Closing a background form from a custom message box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Brief description:
Cannot close form1 by clicking a button that is on form2.

I have the following forms:

`form1`
`formMessageBox` which has `button1`
`form3`

I want to:
Pop up `formMessageBox` from `form1` (this is working ok) then from `formMessageBox`, click `button1` to close `form1` and open `form3`.

I have used a variety of techniques however `form1` cannot be targeted.

Help much appreciated.

*Edit*

When form1 and the messagebox are open at the same time. Form1 does not close or hide when button1 is clicked to try and close form1.

Comment: What don't you show us some of the "variety of techniques" you have used?

Comment: Do not have access to my code right now. However I have tried to

Comment: if you provide your code it would be useful.

Comment: What is `formMessageBox` is it owned by `form1`?  If so you cannot close `form1` from it's modal dialog box `formMessageBox`.  I would research [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @JP: Edited your question. Don't include tags in title !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you're looking for, but I think you are needing something like this.

Say you have `Form1` and you pop up a `formMessageBox` using `ShowDialog()`.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    if (somethingHappened)
    {
        var formMessageBox = new FormMessageBox();

        //ShowDialog() sets the formMessageBox object as a modal dialog owned by Form1 
        DialogResult result = formMessageBox.ShowDialog();

        //Assuming you have OK buttons or something like that in formMessageBox
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var form3 = new Form3();

            /*Can't use this.Close() here as it would close the entire application
            Just hide it and don't forget to dispose of it later when you actually
            want the application to close*/
            this.Hide();

            form3.Show();


        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `formMessageBox` code, just set the `DialogResult` according to what occurs:

```
public class FromMessageBox : Form
{
    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Do some stuff
         this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
         this.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: So this keyword in the above context refers to the form the messagebox has opened from?

Comment: Yes, this is a placeholder for the current instance of the class.  So in the context of `Form1`: `this` = `form1`.  In the context of `FormMessageBox` `this` = `formMessageBox`.

Comment: The comment in the `Form1` code is assuming that `Form1` is the entry point of your application.  If it is not, then you can call `this.Close()`.

Comment: Ok, I think this should work. It sounds logically right for what i want to do. Will check this evening and respond accordingly.

Comment: Great, hope it helps =)

Comment: Thee messagebox closes and form3 shows however form1 does not close.

Comment: Try putting `this.Hide()` above `form3.Show()`

Comment: Yes. Solved. Many Thanks, can you edit that into the answer? then I can tick.

Comment: Edited =)  Tick away ;)